# How to know the meaning of BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy) handle

Tags: bluetooth, handle, gatt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm focusing on BLE hijack. I have capture some BLE data. But I don't know the meaning of those data.
For example:
[image: data]
[image: data2]

I know the band writes something into my phone. But I don't know what exactly it is.
Just like ‘Handle 0x0017’, what does it mean?

Comment: It's my first time to use stackoverflow. Could you tell me how to upload pictures?

Comment: I've helped you upload the image

Comment: @UNICYCLEZRDEBESTINDEHERE Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you are going to attempt to do this sort of thing then you really need to have a good understanding of the underlying protocols and data formats. I can't really explain that in detail in this forum. Go read the specs or a good book (Bluetooth Low Energy: The Developers Handbook by Robin Heydon is one I've used and recommend). Specifically to your question. Each attribute in BLE has a corresponding Attribute Handle. This is effectively a 16-bit address that can be used in Read/Write operations to indicate which attribute to operate on.

Comment: @kaylum I have read the book about BLE and I know the relation between services, characteristics and descriptor. As the pictures show, slave give a kind of data with the value of 0x0010 to the master and the ID of this kind of data is 0x0017. So I want to know what kind of data it is, heart rate, running speed or something else?  If I miss understand, could you tell me what it is? I would appreciate it very much. :)

Comment: You have to look at the service definitions of the device to know what that value means. That's a higher order function and you can't know it just be looking at the low level packets (it's like looking at an IP packet and trying to work out what the application context is). If you don't have the service definitions then you need to do reverse engineering and that procedure is not something that can be described in a few short sentences.

Comment: @kaylum OK. I get it!!! You give a good analog. I think I know where I'm wrong. :)  And you mention the reverse engineering. So reversing hardware(firmware) or App on the phone?  By which one can I get the service definition?